# How do you pronounce IIS?

Tags: iis

I would always just spell it out saying "Eye Eye Ess," but my boss always calls it "Two Ess," like the II is roman numeral. I know it stands for Internet Information so it is not really numbers, but on the other hand it is a lot easier to say "Two Ess."

Comment: "Two Ess" is a very pointy-haired thing to say.

Comment: +1. Pointy headed indeed

Comment: What about doubEyeEss (double Eye Ess)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I pronounce it "Eye Eye Ess" as well. To pronounce it "two ess" is moronic, even if easier to say.

Similarly I prefer to say "Ess Queue Ell" rather than "Sequel" but at least "Sequel" is closer to the mark to SQL than "two ess" is to IIS.

Comment: I've never understood why people use "Sequel," given that "Squirrel" is a much more accurate representation of its function.

Comment: Lol. I like that way of saying it.

Comment: Microsoft markets their DBMS as "Sequel" Server, but the correct pronunciation of mySQL is "My Ess Cue El". Just throwing it out there :)

Answer (score 20):

I pronounce it the same way I pronounce various expletives.

Comment: Wish I could give this one +2

Answer (score 5):

Eye, Eye, Ess

Also, does your boss pronounce SQL "squall"?

Comment: Heh, never heard "squall" but I know a few people who I'd now expect it from.

Answer (score 3):

If it were a UNIX shop, would he pronounce 'vi' as Six?

Comment: Almost certainly (and some people do).

Answer (score 0):

I say eye eye ess too, I don't really think you could call it anything else, aprt from the full proper name.